# How to create a list of all values within a certain range from each other?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples:

```
x = [(2, 10), (4, 5), (8, 10), (9, 11), (10, 15)]
```

I'm trying to compare the first values in all the tuples to see if they are within 1 from each other. If they are within 1, I want to aggregate (sum) the second value of the tuple, and take the mean of the first value.

The output list would look like this:

```
[(2, 10), (4, 5), (9, 36)]
```

Notice that the 8 and 10 have a difference of 2, but they're both only 1 away from 9, so they all 3 get aggregated.

I have been trying something along these lines, but It's not capturing the sequenced values like 8, 9, and 10. It's also still preserving the original values, even if they've been aggregated together.

```
tuple_list = [(2, 10), (4, 5), (8, 10), (9, 11), (10, 15)]

output_list = []
for x1,y1 in tuple_list:
    for x2,y2 in tuple_list:
        if x1==x2:
            continue
        if np.abs(x1-x2) <= 1:
            output_list.append((np.mean([x1,x2]), y1+y2))
        else:
            output_list.append((x1,y1))
            
output_list = list(set(output_list))
```

Comment: how exactly are you trying this?

Comment: What if you had `8, 9, 10, 11, 12`?  Should they be condensed into `10`, `9, 10, 11`, or something else?

Comment: I have added what I've been trying. It's a pretty ugly mess, but it's where I'm starting.

Comment: @0x5453, Good question. Ideally, it would condense 8, 9, 10, 11, & 12 into just 10, since they're all 1 apart. If the context helps, in my dataset, the first value corresponds with a day, and the second value is for a number of occurrences on a given day. So if something occurred on days 8, 9, 10, 11, & 12, I want sum up the occurrences (second value in tuple) and represent it for just the center of the day values (the mean of the first values in the tuple).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in a list comprehension using groupby (from itertools).  The grouping key will be the difference between the first value and the tuple's index in the list.  When the values are 1 apart, this difference will be constant and the tuples will be part of the same group.

For example: [2, 4, 8, 9, 10] minus their indexes [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] will give [2, 3, 6, 6, 6] forming 3 groups: [2], [4] and [8 ,9, 10].

```
from itertools import groupby

x = [(2, 10), (4, 5), (8, 10), (9, 11), (10, 15)]

y = [ (sum(k)/len(k),sum(v))                         # output tuple
      for i   in [enumerate(x)]                      # sequence iterator
      for _,g in groupby(x,lambda t:t[0]-next(i)[0]) # group by sequence
      for k,v in [list(zip(*g))] ]                   # lists of keys & values 

print(y)    
[(2.0, 10), (4.0, 5), (9.0, 36)]
```

The `for k,v in [list(zip(*g))]` part is a bit tricky but what it does it transform a list of tuples (in a group) into two lists (k and v) with k containing the first item of each tuple and v containing the second items.

e.g. if `g` is `((8,10),(9,11),(10,15))` then `k` will be `(8,9,10)` and `v` will be `(10,11,15)`

Comment: Wow. Grouping by the difference between value and index blows my mind. I'm not sure if I'd actually use this, personally, because I feel like a month later I'd have forgotten why it works, but it is bizarrely clever.

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks so much for the very creative answer. I had to spend some time deconstructing it, but it does exactly what I need. For any future readers of this question, it's worth noting that the original list (in this example: `x`) needs to be sorted by each tuple's first value for this to work. Use something like this: `x_sorted = sorted(x, key=lambda x: x[0])`

Thanks again @Alain T.

Answer (score 2):

By sorting the list first, and then using [itertools.pairwise](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) to iterate over the next and previous days, this problem starts to become much easier. On sequential days, instead of adding a new item to our final list, we modify the last item added to it. Figuring out the new sum is easy enough, and figuring out the new average is actually super easy because we're averaging sequential numbers. We just need to keep track of how many sequential days have passed and we can use that to get the average.

```
def on_neighboring_days_sum_occurrances(tuple_list):
    tuple_list.sort()
    ret = []
    sequential_days = 1

    # We add the first item now
    # And then when we start looping we begin looping on the second item
    # This way the loop will always be able to modify ret[-1]
    ret.append(tuple_list[0])

    # Python 3.10+ only, in older versions do
    # for prev, current in zip(tuple_list, tuple_list[1:]):
    for prev, current in itertools.pairwise(tuple_list):

        day = current[0]
        prev_day = prev[0]
        is_sequential_day = day - prev_day <= 1

        if is_sequential_day:
            sequential_days += 1
            avg_day = day - sequential_days/2
            summed_vals = ret[-1][1] + current[1]
            ret[-1] = (avg_day, summed_vals)
        else:
            sequential_days = 1
            ret.append(current)

    return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the list and keep track of a single tuple, and iterate from the tuple next to the one that you're tracking till the penultimate tuple in the list because, when the last tuple comes into tracking there is no tuple after that and thus it is a waste iteration; and find if the difference between the 1st elements is equal to the difference in indices of the tuples, if so sum up the 2nd as well as 1st elements, when this condition breaks, divide the sum of 1st elements with the difference in indices so as to get the average of them, and append them to the result list, now to make sure the program doesn't consider the same tuples again, jump to the index where the condition broke... like this

```py
x = [(2, 10), (4, 5), (8, 10), (9, 11), (10, 15)]
x.sort()

res, i = [], 0

while i<len(x)-1:
    sum2, avg1 = x[i][1], x[i][0]

    for j in range(i+1, len(x)):
        if abs(x[j][0]-x[i][0]) == (j-i):
            sum2 += x[j][1]
            avg1 += x[j][0]
        else:
            res.append(x[i])
            i+=1
            break
    else:
        avg1 /= len(x)-i
        res.append((int(avg1), sum2))
        i = j+1

print(res)
```

Here the `while` loop iterates from the start of the list till the penultimate tuple in the list, the `sum2`, `avg1` keeps track of the 2nd and 1st elements of the current tuple respectively. The `for` loop iterates through the next tuple to the current tuple till the end. The `if` checks the condition, and if it is met, it adds the elements of the tuple from the `for` loop since the variables are intialized with the elements of current tuple, else it appends the tuple from the `for` loop directly to the result list `res`, increments the `while` loop variable and breaks out of the iteration. When the `for` loop culminates without a break, it means that the condition breaks, thus it finds the average of the 1st element and appends the tuple `(avg1, sum2)` to `res` and skips to the tuple which is next to the one that broke the condition.